# Emacs color theme setting

Tags: emacs

i'm now configure my own emacs color theme , base on the color-theme plugin.

i just can't find how to define the status bar's color (where the current line number ,file name ,mode is shown ) .such as if you use color-theme-jb-simple , the status bar's color is likely blue4 ,but i can't find where it is defined .anyone knows ?

thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

I tried vpit3833's answer with `'modeline`, but got an error on startup:
`error: Invalid face, modeline`

After some searching, I created the following:

```
;  I use the following with TERM=xterm-256color
(set-face-foreground 'mode-line "#606060")
(set-face-background 'mode-line "#202020")
(set-face-foreground 'mode-line-inactive "#606060")
(set-face-background 'mode-line-inactive "#202020")
```

My terminal is Xterm (with `export TERM=xterm-256color`), on Ubuntu 14.04 and Emacs version `24.3+1-2ubuntu1`.

Update: I now set `TERM=xterm-256color` via a line in my `~/.Xdefaluts` file:
`xterm*termName:  xterm-256color`

You may find the following diagnostics to be useful:

```
M-x list-colors-display
M-x list-faces-display
```

Related links:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Colors.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html

Answer (score 3):

`(set-face-background 'modeline "Blue")` makes my modeline (what you call status bar is called modeline in Emacs) blue.

Comment: thanks , i found it     (modeline ((t (:background "darkblue" :foreground "yellow"))))